# I can't login in my ip-cam through webview

Tags: android, webview, ip-camera, login-script, mobile-development

I am trying to make an app that can view my ipcam.
I tried doing it by using my webview

```
    }
        String url = "http://";
        WebView view = (WebView) this.findViewById(R.id.glennView);
        view.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        view.loadUrl(url);
    }
```

But it is telling me that the user name and password is wrong. When I type in the `URL` in my web browser it does ask for my username and password. But not through the app.

Can anyone help me with this ?

thanks in advance

Stephen

Comment: Try sending a [basic auth header](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication#Client_side).

Comment: Its almost certainly using saved auth info in a cookie on your web browser

Comment: thank you all so much this works perfect